Understanding Narrative VAR Shocks
Initially VAR studies used shocks to the equation innovations to derive the impulse responses. Later literature uses "narrative" shocks that are drawn from separate regression analysis.
I’m having difficulty understanding what changes to the basic VAR-Cholesky setup is required to implement these narrative shock exercises. Can anyone offer a simple explanation or else direct me to a source that explains this rigorously but straightforwardly.
